# Assertion failure in -[XMPPRoster initWithRosterStorage:dispatchQueue:]

Tags: ios

```
[userArry removeAllObjects];//mutable array
NSManagedObjectContext *Context = [_xmppRosterStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];        
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *ary = [Context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *obj in ary)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"jid"]);
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[obj valueForKey:@"jid"],@"jid",[obj valueForKey:@"displayName"],@"displayName",[obj valueForKey:@"jidStr"] ,@"jidStr",[obj valueForKey:@"photo"],@"photo",nil];

    [userArry addObject:dic];
}

if (userArry.count>0)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:nil];
}
```

> App crash while perform segue with error Assertion failure in -[XMPPRoster initWithRosterStorage:dispatchQueue:], Pods/XMPPFramework/Extensions/Roster/XMPPRoster.m:63
>    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: storage != nil'

Help me please i am not familiar with XMPP

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: _xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] init]; add this line into your code